# Cannot perform task in python loop

Tags: python, loops, csv, python-2.7, numpy

I am matching ID fields from two csv files by a date and location code, both files look like this (with different IDs, of course):

```
ID   code   date
543  452   '1/4/2009'
543  452   '1/8/2009'
543  452   '2/1/2009'
543  452   '2/14/2009'
543  452   '3/6/2009'
543  452   '3/9/2009'
874  210   '1/4/2009'
874  210   '1/9/2009'
874  210   '1/24/2009'
874  210   '2/7/2009'
```

I am loading these as numpy arrays and then looping through, however I cannot perform a certain task in the loop. I need to create a subset array from my second csv (vms) of all records that match a record in the first csv (lb). Here is the code I am working with:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

lb = np.genfromtxt('file2009.csv',dtype = None, delimiter = ',', names = True)
vms = np.genfromtxt('2009final.csv',dtype = None, delimiter = ',', names = True)

id_list = list(set(lb['ID']))

matchList = defaultdict(list)

for e in id_list:
    log = lb[lb['ID']==e]
    vms_list = vms[ np.logical_and(vms['date']==log[0]['date'] , vms['code']==log[0]['code'] )] 
    vms_id_list = list(set(vms_list['ID']))
    for row in log:
        if len(vms_id_list) == 1:
            break
        else:
            vmsIDs = vms[vms['ID'] == vms_id_list[0]]
            vms_ids = str(vms_id_list)
            for every in vms:
                if str(every['ID']) in vms_ids:
                    vmsIDs = np.hstack([vmsIDs, every])
            vms_id_list = []
            vms_list = vmsIDs[ np.logical_and(vmsIDs['date']==row['date'] , vmsIDs['code']==row['code'] )]
            vms_id_list = list(set(vms_list['ID']))
    matchList[e].append(vms_id_list)
```

When I run the code, no error is sprung from it but it is very clear that the line:
`vms_list = vms[ np.logical_and(vms['date']==log[0]['date'] , vms['code']==log[0]['code'] )]`
is not running correctly as vms_list is empty which generates an error later on at the line `vmsIDs = vms[vms['ID'] == vms_id_list[0]]`.
I am really confused because the list is created, it is just completely empty even though I know there are many records that meet the criteria.
If I simply copy the line of code out of the loop and run it independently it works fine, so the problem lies in it performing in the loop. I have no idea why this would not work, I have even tried changing the language from a numpy logical_and to:

```
for e in id_list:
    log = lb[lb['ID']==e]
    for each in vms:
        if each['date'] == log[0]['date'] and each['code'] == log[0]['code']:
            vms_id_list.append(each['ID'])
```

But it does not work, the list is empty. The entire point of this step is to get a list of the IDs from vms that match the criteria of a line from lb. But it still does not work, the list is empty. Is there some sort of lock that I am not seeing? Is there a different way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: I would suggest adding some debug output in places where you have certain expectations about the state of certain variables. Is `log` how you would expect it to be?

Comment: Wow. I have no idea why this worked this time, because I swear I tried trouble-shooting with this before posting. By simply adding 'print vms_list' after the line of code, the script actually works. I guess for whatever reason vms_list wasn't storing completely or something like that.

Comment: @AlmaThom You can post your finding as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment section, for whatever reason this code was just not storing my list correctly, but when prompted to print the list it is stored and the script runs correctly. Here is the finished script:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

lb = np.genfromtxt('file2009.csv',dtype = None, delimiter = ',', names = True)
vms = np.genfromtxt('2009final.csv',dtype = None, delimiter = ',', names = True)

id_list = list(set(lb['ID']))

matchList = defaultdict(list)

for e in id_list:
    log = lb[lb['ID']==e]
    vms_list = vms[ np.logical_and(vms['date']==log[0]['date'] , vms['code']==log[0]['code'] )]
    print vms_list 
    vms_id_list = list(set(vms_list['ID']))
    for row in log:
        if len(vms_id_list) == 1:
            break
        else:
            vmsIDs = vms[vms['ID'] == vms_id_list[0]]
            vms_ids = str(vms_id_list)
            for every in vms:
                if str(every['ID']) in vms_ids:
                    vmsIDs = np.hstack([vmsIDs, every])
            vms_id_list = []
            vms_list = vmsIDs[ np.logical_and(vmsIDs['date']==row['date'] , vmsIDs['code']==row['code'] )]
            vms_id_list = list(set(vms_list['ID']))
    matchList[e].append(vms_id_list)
```